# Getting a Parser error when trying to parse XML 3.5 files in Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to parse XML version 3.5 files in Perl.

The first line of the file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="3.5" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

I have tried both XML::Simple and XML::LibXML and they are both resulting in the same error:

```
parser error : Unsupported version \'3.5\' <?xml version="3.5" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Does anyone perhaps have any suggestions on a way to fix this or an alternate library I can use?  I tried to Google, but there didn't seem to be very many useful solutions to the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should say where you got the notion that your XML data is version 3.5.

Comment: The source file from our supplier has xml version="3.5", so I assume they are violating the RFC then?

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. I see according to the RFC, 1.0 and 1.1 are the only supported versions?

Comment: I have moved my comments into an answer.

Comment: They are probably misusing the XML version field to store the version of their schema. A good place to store that would be as an attribute on the root element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no version 3.5 of XML, only 1.0 and 1.1 (1.0 is the one which is commonly used) as [standardised by the W3C](https://www.w3.org/standards/techs/xml).

It's tempting to speculate that this data came from the future, where XML actually has versions beyond 1, but I suspect it's more likely that there was some misunderstanding and the document is in version 3.5 of some specific XML-based format, and the version was incorrectly added into the opening header.

Your only options are:

- persuade whoever generated the file to fix their mistake
- replace the 3.5 with 1.0 before parsing the file, and hope they haven't made other mistakes which will prevent it being parsed